# How to style the option's position of an html “select” element?

Tags: html, css

I use this code to init a select:

```css
select {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Select a product</option>
  <option>Product 1</option>
  <option>Product 2</option>
  <option>Product 3</option>
</select>
```

But I wanna change the postion of option like this:
[image]

How could I do that? Thanks for any help.

Comment: `select` is one of the least customisable (and most visually inconsistent) elements in modern browsers, generally it's just easier to build your own display element that mirrors a hidden select element's value/functionality (Or use one of the many libraries that does that for you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible with native `select`.
You can read more about it at [MDN - Why is styling form widgets challenging?, The Ugly](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Styling_web_forms#The_ugly).

You can hide first `option` but user won't be able to select it again anymore.

```css
select option:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected>Select a product</option>
  <option>Product 1</option>
  <option>Product 2</option>
  <option>Product 3</option>
</select>
```